# How to retrieve Bitmap with Picasso or Universal Android Loader?

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader, picasso

Here is my actuel code :

```
  public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    // initilize the default HTTP client object
    final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //forming a HttpGet request 
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        //check 200 OK for success
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + 
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;

        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                // getting contents from the stream 
                inputStream = entity.getContent();

                // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                inputStream.reset();
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
    }
    return bitmap;
}`
```

I want to do the same in my function but with Picasso library or Universal Image Loader. Is there a way with these librarys to return juste a Bitmap with an url ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both can and both have already been answered on this site.

Using Picasso:

```
private Target mTarget = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
          // Do whatever you want with the Bitmap
      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}

...

Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(mTarget);
```

You have to keep a reference to the `Target` instance at least as long as the request is in progress. You can cancel the loading later by calling `cancelRequest()`.

Using UIL:

```
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
         // Do whatever you want with the Bitmap
    }
});
```

Comment: You **have** to keep a reference to the `Target` with Picasso or it will be garbage collected. You can also just call `.get()` for the `Bitmap` if you are on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you Jake, I never used that feature but indeed I just saw that in the documentation. I'm editing the answer.